# styles in composition API can hide the object

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-composition-api

hi i used to use Options API and i converted my code completely to composition API but now im having a problem with styles which hides the original object i dunno what differs between these APIs but it should not affect the styling this is my both examples in both APIs
first is composition api

```js
<script setup>
import {
  QCalendarDay,
  addToDate,
  parseTimestamp,
  isBetweenDates,
  today,
  parsed,
  parseTime
} from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/index.js'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarVariables.sass'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarTransitions.sass'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarDay.sass'

import { ref ,computed} from 'vue'
import NavigationBar from '../components/NavigationBar.vue'
    const calendar=ref(null)
    const  selectedDate=ref(today())
     const events=ref([
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Meeting',
          details: 'Time to pitch my idea to the company',
          date: today(),
          time: '09:00',
          duration: 120,
          bgcolor: 'red',
          icon: 'fas fa-handshake'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Lunch',
          details: 'Company is paying!',
          date: today(),
          time: '12:00',
          duration: 60,
          bgcolor: 'teal',
          icon: 'fas fa-hamburger'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Conference',
          details: 'Teaching Javascript 101',
          date: today(),
          time: '13:00',
          duration: 240,
          bgcolor: 'blue',
          icon: 'fas fa-chalkboard-teacher'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'Girlfriend',
          details: 'Meet GF for dinner at Swanky Restaurant',
          date: today(),
          time: '19:00',
          duration: 180,
          bgcolor: 'teal-2',
          icon: 'fas fa-utensils'
        }
      ]
    )

  // computed: {
    // convert the events into a map of lists keyed by date
 const   eventsMap = computed(() => {
      const map = {}
      // this.events.forEach(event => (map[ event.date ] = map[ event.date ] || []).push(event))
      events.value.forEach(event => {
        if (!map[ event.date ]) {
          map[ event.date ] = []
        }
        map[ event.date ].push(event)
        if (event.days) {
          let timestamp = parseTimestamp(event.date)
          let days = event.days
          do {
            timestamp = addToDate(timestamp, { day: 1 })
            if (!map[ timestamp.date ]) {
              map[ timestamp.date ] = []
            }
            map[ timestamp.date ].push(event)
          } while (--days > 0)
        }
      })
      return map
    })


  // methods: {
  const  badgeClasses =(event, type)=> {
      let isHeader = type === 'header'
      return {

        [ `text-white bg-${ event.bgcolor }` ]: true,
        'full-width': !isHeader && (!event.side || event.side === 'full'),
        'left-side': !isHeader && event.side === 'left',
        'right-side': !isHeader && event.side === 'right',
        'rounded-border': true

      }

    }

   const badgeStyles = (event, type, timeStartPos = undefined, timeDurationHeight = undefined) =>{
      const s = {}
      if (timeStartPos && timeDurationHeight) {
        s.top = timeStartPos(event.time) + 'px'
        s.height = timeDurationHeight(event.duration) + 'px'
      }
      s[ 'align-items' ] = 'flex-start'
      return s
    }

   const getEvents =(dt) =>{
      // get all events for the specified date
      const events = eventsMap[ dt ] || []

      if (events.length === 1) {
        events[ 0 ].side = 'full'
      }
      else if (events.length === 2) {
        // this example does no more than 2 events per day
        // check if the two events overlap and if so, select
        // left or right side alignment to prevent overlap
        const startTime = addToDate(parsed(events[ 0 ].date), { minute: parseTime(events[ 0 ].time) })
        const endTime = addToDate(startTime, { minute: events[ 0 ].duration })
        const startTime2 = addToDate(parsed(events[ 1 ].date), { minute: parseTime(events[ 1 ].time) })
        const endTime2 = addToDate(startTime2, { minute: events[ 1 ].duration })
        if (isBetweenDates(startTime2, startTime, endTime, true) || isBetweenDates(endTime2, startTime, endTime, true)) {
          events[ 0 ].side = 'left'
          events[ 1 ].side = 'right'
        }
        else {
          events[ 0 ].side = 'full'
          events[ 1 ].side = 'full'
        }
      }

      return events
    }
  const  scrollToEvent =(event) => {
     calendar.value.scrollToTime(event.time, 350)
    }

  const  onToday= ()=> {
     calendar.value.moveToToday()
    }
   const onPrev =() =>{
     calendar.value.prev()
    }
   const onNext =() =>{
     calendar.value.next()
    }

   const onMoved =(data)=> {
      console.log('onMoved', data)
    }
  const  onChange =(data)=> {
      console.log('onChange', data)
    }
   const onClickDate =(data) =>{
      console.log('onClickDate', data)
    }
  const  onClickTime= (data)=> {
      console.log('onClickTime', data)
    }
   const onClickInterval =(data)=> {
      console.log('onClickInterval', data)
    }
   const onClickHeadIntervals =(data) =>{
      console.log('onClickHeadIntervals', data)
    }
   const onClickHeadDay =(data)=> {
      console.log('onClickHeadDay', data)
    }

</script>
```

```css
<style lang="sass" >
.my-event
  position: absolute
  font-size: 12px
  justify-content: center
  margin: 0 1px
  text-overflow: ellipsis
  overflow: hidden
  cursor: pointer

.title
  position: relative
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  height: 100%

.text-white
  color: white

.bg-blue
  background: blue

.bg-green
  background: green

.bg-orange
  background: orange

.bg-red
  background: red

.bg-teal
  background: teal

.bg-grey
  background: grey

.bg-purple
  background: purple

.full-width
  left: 0
  width: calc(100% - 2px)

.left-side
  left: 0
  width: calc(50% - 3px)

.right-side
  left: 50%
  width: calc(50% - 3px)

.rounded-border
  border-radius: 2px
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="subcontent">
    <navigation-bar
      @today="onToday"
      @prev="onPrev"
      @next="onNext"
    />

    <div class="row justify-center">
      <div style="display: flex; max-width: 800px; width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <q-calendar-day
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="selectedDate"
          view="day"
          animated
          bordered
          transition-next="slide-left"
          transition-prev="slide-right"
          no-active-date
          :interval-minutes="15"
          :interval-start="24"
          :interval-count="68"
          :interval-height="28"
          @change="onChange"
          @moved="onMoved"
          @click-date="onClickDate"
          @click-time="onClickTime"
          @click-interval="onClickInterval"
          @click-head-intervals="onClickHeadIntervals"
          @click-head-day="onClickHeadDay"
        >
          <template #head-day-event="{ scope: { timestamp } }">
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 2px;">
              <template
                v-for="event in eventsMap[timestamp.date]"
                :key="event.id"
              >
                <q-badge
                  v-if="!event.time"
                  :class="badgeClasses(event, 'header')"
                  :style="badgeStyles(event, 'header')"
                  style="width: 100%; cursor: pointer; height: 12px; font-size: 10px; margin: 1px;"
                >
                  <div class="title q-calendar__ellipsis">
                    {{ event.title }}
                    <q-tooltip>{{ event.details }}</q-tooltip>
                  </div>
                </q-badge>
                <q-badge
                  v-else
                  :class="badgeClasses(event, 'header')"
                  :style="badgeStyles(event, 'header')"
                  style="margin: 1px; width: 100px; max-width: 100px; height: 100px; max-height: 100px; cursor: pointer"
                  @click="scrollToEvent(event)"
                >
                  <q-tooltip>{{ event.time + ' - ' + event.details }}</q-tooltip>
                </q-badge>
              </template>
            </div>
          </template>

          <template #day-body="{ scope: { timestamp, timeStartPos, timeDurationHeight } }">
            <template
              v-for="event in getEvents(timestamp.date)"
              :key="event.id"
            >
              <div
                 class="my-event"
                :class="badgeClasses(event, 'body')"
                :style="badgeStyles(event, 'body', timeStartPos, timeDurationHeight)"
              >
                <div class="title q-calendar__ellipsis">
                  {{ event.title }}
                  <q-tooltip>{{ event.time + ' - ' + event.details }}</q-tooltip>
                </div>
              </div>
            </template>
          </template>
        </q-calendar-day>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now options api which has styles(badgestyle method only) run flawlessly

```js
<script>
import {
  QCalendarDay,
  addToDate,
  parseTimestamp,
  isBetweenDates,
  today,
  parsed,
  parseTime
} from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/index.js'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarVariables.sass'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarTransitions.sass'
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/QCalendarDay.sass'

import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import NavigationBar from '../components/NavigationBar.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'WeekSlotDayBody',
  components: {
    NavigationBar,
    QCalendarDay
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selectedDate: today(),
      events: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Meeting',
          details: 'Time to pitch my idea to the company',
          date: today(),
          time: '09:00',
          duration: 120,
          bgcolor: 'red',
          icon: 'fas fa-handshake'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Lunch',
          details: 'Company is paying!',
          date: today(),
          time: '12:00',
          duration: 60,
          bgcolor: 'teal',
          icon: 'fas fa-hamburger'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Conference',
          details: 'Teaching Javascript 101',
          date: today(),
          time: '13:00',
          duration: 240,
          bgcolor: 'blue',
          icon: 'fas fa-chalkboard-teacher'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'Girlfriend',
          details: 'Meet GF for dinner at Swanky Restaurant',
          date: today(),
          time: '19:00',
          duration: 180,
          bgcolor: 'teal-2',
          icon: 'fas fa-utensils'
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    // convert the events into a map of lists keyed by date
    eventsMap () {
      const map = {}
      // this.events.forEach(event => (map[ event.date ] = map[ event.date ] || []).push(event))
      this.events.forEach(event => {
        if (!map[ event.date ]) {
          map[ event.date ] = []
        }
        map[ event.date ].push(event)
        if (event.days) {
          let timestamp = parseTimestamp(event.date)
          let days = event.days
          do {
            timestamp = addToDate(timestamp, { day: 1 })
            if (!map[ timestamp.date ]) {
              map[ timestamp.date ] = []
            }
            map[ timestamp.date ].push(event)
          } while (--days > 0)
        }
      })
      return map
    }
  },

  methods: {
    badgeClasses (event, type) {
      const isHeader = type === 'header'
      return {
        [ `text-white bg-${ event.bgcolor }` ]: true,
        'full-width': !isHeader && (!event.side || event.side === 'full'),
        'left-side': !isHeader && event.side === 'left',
        'right-side': !isHeader && event.side === 'right',
        'rounded-border': true
      }
    },

    badgeStyles (event, type, timeStartPos = undefined, timeDurationHeight = undefined) {
      const s = {}
      if (timeStartPos && timeDurationHeight) {
        s.top = timeStartPos(event.time) + 'px'
        s.height = timeDurationHeight(event.duration) + 'px'
      }
      s[ 'align-items' ] = 'flex-start'
      return s
    },

    getEvents (dt) {
      // get all events for the specified date
      const events = this.eventsMap[ dt ] || []

      if (events.length === 1) {
        events[ 0 ].side = 'full'
      }
      else if (events.length === 2) {
        // this example does no more than 2 events per day
        // check if the two events overlap and if so, select
        // left or right side alignment to prevent overlap
        const startTime = addToDate(parsed(events[ 0 ].date), { minute: parseTime(events[ 0 ].time) })
        const endTime = addToDate(startTime, { minute: events[ 0 ].duration })
        const startTime2 = addToDate(parsed(events[ 1 ].date), { minute: parseTime(events[ 1 ].time) })
        const endTime2 = addToDate(startTime2, { minute: events[ 1 ].duration })
        if (isBetweenDates(startTime2, startTime, endTime, true) || isBetweenDates(endTime2, startTime, endTime, true)) {
          events[ 0 ].side = 'left'
          events[ 1 ].side = 'right'
        }
        else {
          events[ 0 ].side = 'full'
          events[ 1 ].side = 'full'
        }
      }

      return events
    },

    scrollToEvent (event) {
      this.$refs.calendar.scrollToTime(event.time, 350)
    },

    onToday () {
      this.$refs.calendar.moveToToday()
    },
    onPrev () {
      this.$refs.calendar.prev()
    },
    onNext () {
      this.$refs.calendar.next()
    },

    onMoved (data) {
      console.log('onMoved', data)
    },
    onChange (data) {
      console.log('onChange', data)
    },
    onClickDate (data) {
      console.log('onClickDate', data)
    },
    onClickTime (data) {
      console.log('onClickTime', data)
    },
    onClickInterval (data) {
      console.log('onClickInterval', data)
    },
    onClickHeadIntervals (data) {
      console.log('onClickHeadIntervals', data)
    },
    onClickHeadDay (data) {
      console.log('onClickHeadDay', data)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

```css
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.my-event
  position: absolute
  font-size: 12px
  justify-content: center
  margin: 0 1px
  text-overflow: ellipsis
  overflow: hidden
  cursor: pointer

.title
  position: relative
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  height: 100%

.text-white
  color: white

.bg-blue
  background: blue

.bg-green
  background: green

.bg-orange
  background: orange

.bg-red
  background: red

.bg-teal
  background: teal

.bg-grey
  background: grey

.bg-purple
  background: purple

.full-width
  left: 0
  width: calc(100% - 2px)

.left-side
  left: 0
  width: calc(50% - 3px)

.right-side
  left: 50%
  width: calc(50% - 3px)

.rounded-border
  border-radius: 2px
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="subcontent">
    <navigation-bar
      @today="onToday"
      @prev="onPrev"
      @next="onNext"
    />

    <div class="row justify-center">
      <div style="display: flex; max-width: 800px; width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <q-calendar-day
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="selectedDate"
          view="day"
          animated
          bordered
          transition-next="slide-left"
          transition-prev="slide-right"
          no-active-date
          :interval-minutes="15"
          :interval-start="24"
          :interval-count="68"
          :interval-height="28"
          @change="onChange"
          @moved="onMoved"
          @click-date="onClickDate"
          @click-time="onClickTime"
          @click-interval="onClickInterval"
          @click-head-intervals="onClickHeadIntervals"
          @click-head-day="onClickHeadDay"
        >
          <template #head-day-event="{ scope: { timestamp } }">
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 2px;">
              <template
                v-for="event in eventsMap[timestamp.date]"
                :key="event.id"
              >
                <q-badge
                  v-if="!event.time"
                  :class="badgeClasses(event, 'header')"
                  :style="badgeStyles(event, 'header')"
                  style="width: 100%; cursor: pointer; height: 12px; font-size: 10px; margin: 1px;"
                >
                  <div class="title q-calendar__ellipsis">
                    {{ event.title }}
                    <q-tooltip>{{ event.details }}</q-tooltip>
                  </div>
                </q-badge>
                <q-badge
                  v-else
                  :class="badgeClasses(event, 'header')"
                  :style="badgeStyles(event, 'header')"
                  style="margin: 1px; width: 10px; max-width: 10px; height: 10px; max-height: 10px; cursor: pointer"
                  @click="scrollToEvent(event)"
                >
                  <q-tooltip>{{ event.time + ' - ' + event.details }}</q-tooltip>
                </q-badge>
              </template>
            </div>
          </template>

          <template #day-body="{ scope: { timestamp, timeStartPos, timeDurationHeight } }">
            <template
              v-for="event in getEvents(timestamp.date)"
              :key="event.id"
            >
              <div
                v-if="event.time !== undefined"
                class="my-event"
                :class="badgeClasses(event, 'body')"
                :style="badgeStyles(event, 'body', timeStartPos, timeDurationHeight)"
              >
                <div class="title q-calendar__ellipsis">
                  {{ event.title }}
                  <q-tooltip>{{ event.time + ' - ' + event.details }}</q-tooltip>
                </div>
              </div>
            </template>
          </template>
        </q-calendar-day>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding .value to     `const events = eventsMap.value[ dt ] || []`

Comment: Seems then like the question was the result of a typo